# Is the initial capacity inferred when using collection initializers?

Tags: c#

When using the collection initializers in C# 3.0, is the initial capacity of the collection inferred from the number of elements used to initialize the collection? For example, is

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

equivalent to

```
List<int> digits = new List<int>(10) { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does using the braced initializer on collection types set the initial capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975450/does-using-the-braced-initializer-on-collection-types-set-the-initial-capacity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

is equivalent to

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>();
temp.Add(0);
temp.Add(1);    
temp.Add(2);    
temp.Add(3);    
temp.Add(4);    
temp.Add(5);    
temp.Add(6);    
temp.Add(7);    
temp.Add(8);    
temp.Add(9);    
List<int> digits = temp;
```

The number of items being added doesn't automatically change the initial capacity.  If you're adding more than 16 items through the collection initializer you can combine the constructor and initializer like this:

```
List<int> digits = new List<int>(32) { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 };
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's equivalent to:

```
// Note the () after <int> - we're calling the parameterless constructor
List<int> digits = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

In other words, the C# compiler doesn't know or care what the parameterless constructor will do - but that's what it will call. It's up to the collection itself to decide what its initial capacity is (if it even has such a concept - a linked list doesn't, for example).

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete. `List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };` is equivalent to `List<int> digits = new List<int>(); digits.Add(0); digits.Add(1); ... digits.Add(9);` The constructor never sees the elements of the collection initializer list. Thus, from the perspective of the constructor, the initializer list plays no role in determining the initial capacity.

Comment: @Jason, actually it's equivalent to using a temp variable to call the constructor, add the items, and then assigning the temp back to the original variable.  The difference here is that if an error occurs in one of the Add() calls, the temp is automatically discarded (as there are no references to it) and the variable "digits" is never assigned anything.

Comment: This answer was *only* meant to address the constructor call, as the question was comparing a collection initializer with an explicit constructor argument list with one without an argument list.